# Issue in dependency injection while implementing Unit testing in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing

My unit testing code is

```
[TestClass]
public class ProjectControllerTest
{
    Mock<IProjectService> addressRepositoryMock = new Mock<IProjectService>();
    ProjectController controller;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        controller = new ProjectController(addressRepositoryMock.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var response = controller.GetOverrides(1) as HttpResponseMessage;
    }
}
```

My controller code is:

```
[Route("GetOverrides")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetOverrides(int Project_Id)
{
        List<OverridesDto> overrides = new List<OverridesDto>();

        try
        {
            overrides = projectService.GetOverrides(Project_Id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Logger.Error(ex, "Exception:{Ex}", null);
            ThrowHttpExceptionOnError(ex.ToString());
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, overrides);
 }
```

I am able to hit method `GetOverrides` in controller from  unit testing project in debug mode but the problem is I can not hit BAL method `projectService.GetOverrides(Project_Id);` which is returning null

Please help me out with the above issue.

Comment: Please review [mcve] guide on posting code. In particular make sure to post how you setup you mock (as I don't see any any calls that configure it like `Setup(...)` if you are using moq for example) and constructor of the controller (where you potentially set `projectService` property)

Comment: ASP.NET MVC **6** was renamed ASP.NET Core MVC - is that what you're using?

Comment: No i'm using asp.net mvc 6 not core mvc